# Find/select today's date from list of 366 days in column A

Tags: excel, vba

I made a calendar sheet in Excel with all 366 days of the year listed in column A
how can I write an Auto_open macro which automatically selects and activates the cell holding the current date?

Comment: Hi Ken, welcome to SO. It's important to understand the community here are not a code writing service. If you haven't already, have a read of [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and include any code you have already written to your question (even if it doesn't work!).

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim cell As Range
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Set cell = Range("A:A").Find(What:=Date, After:=Range("A1"))
    cell.Select
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd write it as:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim CellToCheck As Range

For Each CellToCheck In Sheet1.Range("A1:A366") 'To make dynamic, you could make use of finding lastrow and searching until that row.
    If CellToCheck.Value = Date Then
        CellToCheck.Select
        Exit For
    End If
Next CellToCheck

End Sub
```

Outcome:

[image: Screenshot of today's date selected from range in column A]

For this code to work you need to enter it into the `ThisWorkbook` code module and choose `Workbook` and `Open` from the appropriate drop-down menus, like so:

[image: Screenshot of the VBE showing ThisWorkbook code module set for Workbook_Open event]

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim lastcol As Long
Dim t As Date
Dim u As Date
Dim v As Long
Dim w As Long
Dim notolet As String

Sheets("all").Activate ' your sheet name here
With ActiveSheet
lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lastcol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With

t = Now()
u = Format(t, "dd/mm/yyyy")
notolet = Split(Cells(1, lastcol).Address, "$")(1)

For v = lastrow To 2 Step -1
Select Case Cells(v, 1).Value
    Case u
       Range("A" & v & ":" & notolet & v).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
       Exit For
End Select
Next
w = v
End Sub
```